# Using groupby calculations in Pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am working on a geospatial project where I need to do some calculations between groups of data within a data frame. The data I am using spans over several different years and specific to the Local Authority District code, each year has a numerical ID.

I need to be able to calculate the mean average of a group of years within that data set relative to the LAD code.

```
LAC          LAN                JAN     FEB     MAR     APR     MAY     JUN     ID
K04000001    ENGLAND AND WALES  56597   43555   49641   88049   52315   42577   5
E92000001    ENGLAND            53045   40806   46508   83504   49413   39885   5
```

I can use groupby to calculate the mean based on a LAC, but what I can't do is calculate the mean grouped by LAC for ID 1:3 for example.

What is more efficient, seperate in to seperate dataframes stored in an dict for example, or keep in one dataframe and use an ID?

`df.groupby('LAC').mean()`

I come frome a matlab background so just getting the hang of the best way to do things.

Secondly, once these operatons are complete, I would like to do the following:

(mean of id - 1:5 - mean id:6) using LAC as the key.

Sorry if I haven't explained this very well!

**Edit: Expected output.**

To be able to average a group of rows by specific ID for a given value of LAC.

For example:
Average monthly values for E92000001 rows with ID 3

```
LAC         JAN     FEB     MAR     APR     MAY     JUN    ID
K04000001,  56706   43653   49723   88153   52374   42624   5
K04000001   56597   43555   49641   88049   52315   42577   5
E92000001   49186   36947   42649   79645   45554   36026   5
E92000001   53045   40806   46508   83504   49413   39885   3
E92000001   68715   56476   62178   99174   65083   55555   4
E92000001   41075   28836   34538   71534   37443   27915   3
E92000001   54595   42356   48058   85054   50963   41435   1
```

Rows to be averaged:

```
E92000001   53045   40806   46508   83504   49413   39885   3
E92000001   41075   28836   34538   71534   37443   27915   3
```

Result

```
E92000001   47060   34821   40523   77519   43428   33900   3
```

edit: corrected error.

Comment: please provide an sample as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/6692898)

Comment: Thanks, dodgy copy and paste job. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

To match the update in your question. This will give you a dataframe with only one row for each ID-LAC combination, with the average of all the rows that had that index.

```
df.groupby(['ID', 'LAC']).mean()
```

---

I would start by setting the year and LAC as the index

```
df.set_index(['ID', 'LAC'], inplace=True).sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Now you can groupby Index and get the mean for every month, or even each row's average since the first year.

```
expanding_mean = df.groupby('index').cumsum() / (df.groupby('index').cumcount() + 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting - That still doesn't achieve the result I am looking for though.

Comment: @Owain can you edit your question and add your expected output?